# cannot see source tree in android.dmg.sparseimage in mac osx

Tags: android, macos, diskimage

After syncing the android source code tree in a dynamic extendable disk image (android.dmg.sparseimage) in mac osx (10.6.7), I cannot see anything in there. However the diskimage size has changed to 3.99GB meaning that disk image contains the source tree but may be my silly mistake somewhere made it invisible. I cannot access the files even by terminal.

What did I do wrong? How to make the source tree visible?

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem on Mac OS x 10.7.2. I have an android image mounted to /Volumes/android I initialized repo in /Volumes/android/source, after a 'repo sync' it's size is 6.4 GB (of .repo) but I can't see any code in the file system.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at /Volumes/android/ in the Terminal? Maybe the folder containing the source is hidden? user1022519 was mentioning `.repo`: folders starting with a `.` are usually hidden.